# Publish MS Exchange calendar file for collaboration

Tags: c#, outlook, exchange-server, icalendar

I have an application that holds calendar data / events and now i want people to access this data through Microsoft Outlook (optionally with Exchange as source) as well. 
I want to enable them to add the calendar to Outlook, see the events (as every other Outlook/Exchange calendar), but they also should be able to edit the events as well.

I have seen that Outlook can read ICS files. But i dont think that Outlook can write / alter these files as well.

Is there someone who has a good idea / tool / practice on how to do this job?

My idea is that the best way to accomplish this, is via Exchange. Are there possibilities for my application to sync with a shared calendar in Exchange?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook can save appointments as ICS files just fine (AppoinmmentItem.SaveAs(.., olICal), the problem is that when you double click on an ICS file, Outlook crates a temporary appointment in its store, so when you modify and save the appointment, the changes will not be persisted in the original ICS file.

Why not programmatically create a separate folder in Outlook and export your appointments there? You can detect changes in that folder and copy the modified appointment back to your application if necessary.